# Finding $P(X<2Y)$ given joint pdf $f(x, y) = \frac {1}{2\pi} e^{-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$

Tags: probability, integration

> The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is $$f(x, y) = \frac {1}{2\pi} e^{-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\,; \quad x,y\in \mathbb{R}$$ Find $P(X<2Y)$.

I have tried this:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{2y} f(x, y)\, dx\,dy$$

@StubbornAtom suggested polar transformations. 
So here it goes, 
Let $X = r \cos\theta, \, Y = r \sin\theta$. 
Then The integral gets transformed as $\int \int re^{-r}d\theta$.
Could some one help find the new limits.

Comment: Use polar transformation and draw a picture of the region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is rotationally symmetric, since the density depends only on the distance from the origin. This means that the conditional distribution of $(X,Y)$ given $X^2+Y^2$ is uniformly distributed on the circle of radius $r=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. Writing $X=r\cos\Theta$ and $Y=r\sin\Theta$ with $\Theta\in [0,2\pi)$ uniformly random, we have
$$
\mathbb P(X<2Y\mid X^2+Y^2)=\mathbb P(\cos\Theta<2\sin \Theta)$$$$=\mathbb P\Bigl(\tan\Theta>\frac{1}{2}, \cos\theta > 0\Bigr)+\mathbb P\Bigl(\tan\Theta<\frac{1}{2}, \cos\theta < 0\Bigr),$$
which can be seen to equal
$$\mathbb P\Bigl(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}<\Theta<\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)=\frac12.
$$
Since the conditional probability is $\tfrac12$ independent of $X^2+Y^2$, it follows that the unconditional probability is also $\tfrac12$.

Comment: Thank you...This is really insightful. Could you please elaborate how you came to the solution of 0.5

Comment: @SouravPal saying that $\Theta$ is uniformly random in $[0,2\pi)$ is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb P(a<\Theta<b)=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}$. Just choose $a=\tan^{-1}\tfrac12$ and $b=a+\pi$, so that $b-a=\pi$ and the $\tfrac12$ comes from $\frac{\pi}{2\pi}$.

Comment: How do you know that the conditional distribution of (X,Y) is uniform without calculating the conditional pdf?

Comment: @Prof.Shanku conditional uniformity given $X^2+Y^2$ is an equivalent alternate way of saying that the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is rotationally symmetric. It can be proven abstractly by considering how the quantity $\mathbb P( (X,Y)\in A\mid X^2+Y^2 )$ changes when replacing $A$ with a rotated copy...

Comment: Thank you @pre-kidney

Comment: Could you please help me explain the limits derived from graph of tan theta

Comment: Looking at this answer again, I see my intermediate step $\tan \theta>\tfrac 12$ is slightly the incorrect condition due to sign issues, but the steps before and after it are unchanged. The reason is that going from $\cos\theta<2\sin\theta$ to $\tan\theta>\tfrac 12$ involves dividing by $\cos\theta$, which flips the inequality sign if $\cos\theta$ is negative. So my answer to your question is still to look at the graph of $\tan\theta$, but keep in mind the inequality is flipped when $\tfrac{\pi}2<\theta<\tfrac{3\pi}{2}$ (i.e., between the two infinite spikes of $\tan\theta$).

Answer (score 3):

Draw the set $M = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x<2y\}$. What you should get is the half-plane above the line $y=\frac{x}{2}$. Since the given pdf $f$ is radially symmetric, you get the result
$$
P(X<2Y) = \int_M f(x,y) \, \mathrm dx\,  \mathrm dy = \frac{1}{2}
$$
without any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

if we consider the domain D* symmetrical of D with respect to O, the integral on D * is equal to that on D by parity of the function: f(x,y)=f(-x,-y) and the change (x, y) in (-x, -y)
and as D and D* are disjoint and DUD*= RxR  (to see on the drawing!)
the integral sought is half of that on RXR

Answer (score -1):

So this is my version that I have understood from @pre-kidney's answer please note that this is just an elaboration of his answer.

$f(x, y) = \frac {1}{2\pi} e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \ ;\  -\infty<\ x \ <\infty\ ; -\infty < y < \infty$

$X=rcosθ,Y=rsinθ$

$f(r, \theta) = f(\theta).f(r) = (\frac {1}{2\pi} ).(re^{-r})\ \ ;\ \ 0 < r < \infty\ ;\ 0 <  \theta < 2\pi$

Now, $P(X < 2Y) = P(rcos\theta < 2rsin\theta) = P(tan\theta > \frac {1}{2}) = P(\theta > tan^-\frac {1}{2}) = \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{tan^-\frac {1}{2}}^{2 \pi}d\theta = \frac {1}{2\pi} [\theta]_{tan^-\frac {1}{2}}^{\pi + tan^-\frac {1}{2}} = \frac {1}{2\pi}[\pi + tan^-\frac {1}{2} - -tan^-\frac {1}{2}]) = \frac {1}{2\pi} . \pi = 0.5$

Comment: It is not right that you unaccepted my solution, then posted a modified version of it (with added mistakes) and accepted that one instead. Please take a careful look at my solution and if there is a step you do not understand (which appears to be the step where $\mathbb P(\theta>\tan^{-1}\tfrac 12)$ is turned into $\mathbb P(a<\theta<b)$ for appropriate $a,b$) you should ask that directly as a comment on my answer. Your bounds are wrong because you got $a$ correct and $b$ incorrect. Look at a plot of $\tan \theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ to see where it goes about the line $y=\tfrac 12$.

Comment: I apologize my friend. I am new on this platform, and am still not privy with the appropriate conventions followed by it's members. This is an attempt to very my understanding of the problem-solution. I have re-accepted your solution. I finally understand the limits 0 to 2$\pi$.